# JS on change does not apply when value is allready selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="premium">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="free">

<div id="paypremium">Premium infos</div>

$('[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
        $('#paypremium').toggle(this.value == 'premium');
      }).change();
```

if I check the related radio button the wanted div appear just fine.
However if the radio button is prechecked the related div is not displayed... it works only when I actively click on the radio button.

How can I make the div appear if the radio button is pre-checked?

EDIT : Problem is solved, however I realised that another piece of code is preventing the code to work

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#paypremium').toggle(this.value == 'premium');
  }).filter(':checked').change();
});
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing in your code causes a div to appear / disappear, but you're asking how to make a div appear :/ ?

Comment: I added the current html ... for now this code makes the div appear as I click on the premium radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with using `.change()` your code will loop through all the `[name="type"]` radio inputs and it'll give you the action for the last one .. this mean if your `premium` radio is not the last radio the div it disappear .. you need to use `.filter(':checked').change();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#paypremium').toggle(this.value == 'premium');
  }).filter(':checked').change();
});
```

```css
#paypremium{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="type" checked value="premium">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="free">

<div id="paypremium">Premium infos</div>
```

Comment: @agone07 this code working well in the snippet as you can see .. 1st: I added `display:none;` to the div to make it invisible by default .. 2nd: I added `checked` to the premium radio input .. 3rd: I added `.filter(':checked')` before `.change()` that's it .. If the code not working with you you need to check your console for errors or check your code again or just copy/paste the code

Comment: yep I tried it in a test doc... it is working.. there is probably something else in my code causing issues to this code

Comment: I found out the piece of code preventing this to work... I edited my post... can you see something wrong with the first part of the code? (it is the code for prettyphoto)

Comment: @agone07 I can't tell you there is something wrong or not without checking the console errors .. if this part causing the problem it must be appear on your browser console

Comment: That is what I have in console... don't know jquerry or js enough to understand it

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (95:291)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: @agone07 `prettyPhoto is not a function` tis mean your plugin not included .. edit your answer with how you link your scripts

Comment: It's another topic I think as I managed to go around it by moving this script below the one you gave me... thanks for your help